# Linha em branco template Elixir

Tags: template, elixir

Esse código exibe uma mensagem se ela existir, porém quando não existe, exibe uma linha branca:

```
<%= if @comprovante["transacao"]["complemento"] do %>OBSERVACAO: <%= @comprovante["transacao"]["complemento"]%><% else %><% end %>
```

como faço pra não exibir essa linha em branco?

Answer (score 2):

A linha em branca que está sendo exibida é condição do else e como não tem nada está retornando nil, o que faz ficar uma linha em branco, para evitar basta retirar o else ou colocar um retorno para o mesmo.

```
<%= if @comprovante["transacao"]["complemento"] do %> OBSERVACAO: <%= @comprovante["transacao"]["complemento"]%><% end %>
```